# confusion with fseek() in C

Tags: c

I am new to the C programming language. I am learning file I/O, and am confused with the fseek function. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct threeNumbers {
int n1,n2,n3;
}
int main (){
int n;
struct threeNumbers number;
FILE *filePointer;
if ((filePointer=fopen("\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\haseeb\\learningC\\file Input and Output\\program2\\program.bin","rb"))==NULL){
printf("error! opening file);
/* if pointer is null, the program will exit */
exit(1);
}
/* moves the cursore at the end of the file*/
fseek(filePointer,-sizeof(struct threeNumbers),SEEK_END);
for(n=1;n<5;++n){
fread(&number,sizeof(struct threeNumbers),1,filePointer);
printf (" n1:%i\tn2:%i\tn3:",number.n1,number.n2,number.n3);
fseek(filePointer,-2*sizeof(struct threeNumbers),SEEK_CUR);
}
fclose(filePointer);
return 0;
}
```

I know that this program will start reading the records from the file program.bin in the reverse order (last to first) and prints it.
my confusion is I know that "fseek(filePointer,-sizeof(struct threeNumbers),SEEK_END);" will move the cursor at the end of the binary file. What does "fseek(filePointer,-2*sizeof(struct threeNumbers),SEEK_CUR);" do? I think it moves to the current location, but what is the point of the cursor cumming to the current location in this program? Also why is it -2 instead of being just "-sizeof(struct threeNumbers)"?

Comment: There is a `"` missing in `printf("error! opening file);` That is why the syntax highlighting in your code doesn't work.

Comment: `FILE *filePointer = fopen( ... );` and then `if ( filePointer == NULL ) ...` is a ***LOT*** easier to read and get correct than cramming the assignment into the `if` statement.  Cramming assignments into `if` statements is a ***bad idea*** that leads to hard-to-read code that's bug-prone.  Whoever is teaching you to do that has never been on 24-hour call to fix bugs in production code.

Comment: Besides the missing end quote, `printf("error! opening file");` has other issues.  It is the canonical example of a useless error message, and it's being written to the wrong place.  Write the error message to stderr, include the path used to open the file, and include the reason for the error.  `FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode); if( fp == NULL ) { perror(path); ...`

Comment: It would be easier to read the file sequentially into an array of `struct` in reverse index sequence: `for(n=4; n>=0; n--)` and then print the results, with no seeking needed.

Comment: The reason it moves back `-2` structs is because after reading one `struct` the file pointer is at the next position after, therefore you need to move back 2 structs to be at the start of the previous one. If you only move back 1 struct you will keep on reading the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the actual code, this is what `fseek()` does:

```text
       The  fseek()  function  sets the file position indicator for the stream
       pointed to by stream.  The new position, measured in bytes, is obtained
       by  adding offset bytes to the position specified by whence.  If whence
       is set to SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END, the offset  is  relative  to
       the  start of the file, the current position indicator, or end-of-file,
       respectively.  A successful call to the  fseek()  function  clears  the
       end-of-file  indicator  for  the  stream  and undoes any effects of the
       ungetc(3) function on the same stream.
```

`fseek(filePointer,-sizeof(struct threeNumbers),SEEK_END)` will *not* "move the cursor at the end of the binary file"; it will move it `sizeof(struct threeNumbers)` before the end of the file.

Comment: And the same applies to `SEEK_CUR`, it does not `moves to the current location` as OP thinks.